# Number of subsets transversal both to a finite set and to its complement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a set $V$ of $n$ elements and a subset $A$ of fixed cardinality $2 \le k \le n-2$. How many subsets $Y$ are there such that $Y \cap A \neq \emptyset \wedge Y \cap A^c \neq \emptyset \wedge A \not\subseteq Y \wedge Y \not\supseteq A^c$. Moreover I want that $Y \neq V$.

Comment: You say $Y$ is to be a subset, but of which set: $V$ or $A$? And do you mean that $A\subseteq V$? Also, your requirements seem to be redundant.

Comment: $Y$ is a subset of $V$. I've said that $A \subset V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to choose

A) a nonempty proper subset of $A$ and

B) a nonempty proper subset of $A^c$.

Their union will be a proper subset of V which has the required properties.

We have $ 2^k-2 $ ways to do A, and $2^{n-k}-2$ ways to do B.
So we can choose such Y in  $ (2^k-2) \times (2^{n-k}-2)$ ways.